# CoreData+CloudKit integration issue

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

I'm trying to setup CoreData+CloudKit integration. But I receive following errors right after `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` configuration.

```
 CoreData: error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _performSetupRequest:]_block_invoke(939): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x282d18a90>: Failed to set up CloudKit integration for store: <NSSQLCore: 0x10342fbf0> (URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/18992BCF-7F0C-4271-B106-947B8F52A723/Library/Application%20Support/App.sqlite)
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "A Core Data error occurred." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The mirroring delegate could not initialize because it's store was removed from the coordinator.}
```

Here is the code of persistent container setup:

```swift
self.persistentContainer = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: containerName)
 
let localStorage = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storageURL)
let localStorageOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: "iCloud.com.myapp")
localStorageOptions.databaseScope = .private
localStorage.cloudKitContainerOptions = localStorageOptions
persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions = [localStorage]
   
persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
  if let error = error {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

Another thing to mention is that `storageURL` is a shared app group folder.

Not sure what exactly went wrong here, so would be happy to get any help!

#### **Update**

Adding full setup code, with storage path creation.

```swift
  setupPersistentContainer(
    containerName: "Model",
    sharedGroupIdentifier: "group.com.example.group.name",
    cloudKitIdentifier: "iCloud.com.example.icloud.name"
  )

  func setupPersistentContainer(
    containerName: String, 
    sharedGroupIdentifier: String, 
    cloudKitIdentifier: String
  ) {
    persistentContainer = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: containerName)
    
    guard let storageURL = sharedStorageURL(for: sharedGroupIdentifier) else {
      // error
      return
    }
    
    let localStorage = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storageURL)
    let localStorageOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: cloudKitIdentifier)
    localStorageOptions.databaseScope = .private
    localStorage.cloudKitContainerOptions = localStorageOptions
    persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions = [localStorage]
    
    persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
      if let error = error {
        fatalError()
      }
      
      print(storeDescription)
    }
  }
  
  // MARK: - Private
  private func sharedStorageURL(for identifier: String) -> URL? {
    guard let containerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: identifier) else {
      return nil
    }
    
    return containerURL
      .appendingPathComponent("StorageFolder")
      .appendingPathComponent("Model.sqlite")
  }
```

Comment: The issue is likely your url. Especially because your error does not show the app group as the storage location look at this [from apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit) and [avanderlee](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/core-data-app-extension-data-sharing/). From the second link you can learn to get a valid AppGroup URL for the description. Also, you should verify that the container url is correct. The usually pattern is `"iCloud.com.business.myapp"`

Comment: thank you for an answer @loremipsum. The iCloud id is just an example, it's correct in real env. 
You're right folder path is incorrect in log example. Tried same with correct App Groups link and receive same error. And same without groups like in example logs.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @loremipsum Added full setup code, including path creation.

Comment: You still aren't providing a minimal reproducible example but are you calling `setupPersistentContainer` twice by any chance? Put a `print` in it and check

Comment: Only once @loremipsum

Comment: I’m not going to keep guessing. Start a clean project and try to duplicate it into a minimal reproducible example